# Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: select, hive

I have a local file movies.dat formatted as movie_id:movie_title:genre. For example:
1:movie1:Comedy
2:movie2:Drama
3:movie3:Horror
...
I create an external table using the following command.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movies(movie_id INT, movie_title String, genre String)
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\:' -- need backslash!!
LOCATION '/exc103320/movies_copy'; -- name of the directory to copy the original file
```

Then, I load the data to the table by

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'movies.dat' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE movies;
```

When I run  `SELECT * FROM movies LIMIT 3;`
I see the first 3 rows.
When I run `SELECT movie_id FROM movies LIMIT 3;` I get the following error

Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1420729875693_6595, Tracking URL = http://cshadoop1.utdallas.edu:8088/proxy/application_1420729875693_6595/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop-2.4.1/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1420729875693_6595
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2015-03-29 17:14:54,820 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1420729875693_6595 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://cshadoop1.utdallas.edu:8088/cluster/app/application_1420729875693_6595
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you dont need the backlash in the "ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY" statement.

Try the DDL statement like this and see if it works.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE movies(movie_id INT, movie_title String, genre String)
ROW FORMAT
DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' 
LOCATION '/exc103320/movies_copy';